# failed: exceeded CUs meter at BPF instruction

Tags: anchor, metaplex, nft, transfer

I have an instruction which transfers tokens, pnft and closes the account. I get the above error when I call the instruction from the frontend.

Here's the instruction code

```
pub fn handler(ctx: Context<Repay>, interest_amount: u64) -> Result<()> {
    let loan_account = &mut ctx.accounts.loan_account;
    loan_account.status = LoanStatus::Repaid;
    loan_account.end_time = Clock::get()?.unix_timestamp;

    let amount = loan_account.terms.principal + interest_amount;

    // transfer principal + interest from borrower to lender
    anchor_lang::system_program::transfer(
        CpiContext::new(
            ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
            anchor_lang::system_program::Transfer {
                from: ctx.accounts.borrower.to_account_info(),
                to: ctx.accounts.lender.to_account_info(),
            },
        ),
        amount,
    )?;

    // transfer pnft from loan vault to borrower
    let transfer_ix = TransferBuilder::new()
        .metadata(ctx.accounts.metadata.key())
        .mint(ctx.accounts.nft_mint.key())
        .authority(ctx.accounts.vault_authority.key())
        .payer(ctx.accounts.borrower.key())
        .token(ctx.accounts.loan_nft_vault.key())
        .token_owner(ctx.accounts.vault_authority.key())
        .destination(ctx.accounts.borrower_nft_account.key())
        .destination_owner(ctx.accounts.borrower.key())
        .owner_token_record(ctx.accounts.owner_token_record.key())
        .destination_token_record(ctx.accounts.destination_token_record.key())
        .edition(ctx.accounts.edition.key())
        .authorization_rules(ctx.accounts.auth_rules.key())
        .authorization_rules_program(ctx.accounts.auth_rules_program.key())
        .build(TransferArgs::V1 {
            amount: 1,
            authorization_data: None,
        })
        .unwrap()
        .instruction();

    msg!("setting transfer ix accounts");

    let transfer_infos = vec![
        ctx.accounts.metadata.to_account_info(),
        ctx.accounts.nft_mint.to_account_info(),
        ctx.accounts.vault_authority.to_account_info(),
        ctx.accounts.loan_nft_vault.to_account_info(),
        ctx.accounts.borrower_nft_account.to_account_info(),
        ctx.accounts.borrower.to_account_info(),
        ctx.accounts.owner_token_record.to_account_info(),
        ctx.accounts.destination_token_record.to_account_info(),
        ctx.accounts.edition.to_account_info(),
        ctx.accounts.auth_rules.to_account_info(),
        ctx.accounts.auth_rules_program.to_account_info(),
        ctx.accounts.sysvar_instructions.to_account_info(),
        ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
        ctx.accounts.associated_token_program.to_account_info(),
        ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
    ];

    msg!("invoking transfer ix");
    invoke_signed(
        &transfer_ix,
        &transfer_infos,
        &[&[
            VAULT_AUTHORITY_SEED.as_bytes(),
            &[ctx.accounts.loan_account.vault_authority_bump],
        ]],
    )?;

    // close loan nft token account
    anchor_spl::token::close_account(CpiContext::new_with_signer(
        ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
        anchor_spl::token::CloseAccount {
            account: ctx.accounts.loan_nft_vault.to_account_info(),
            destination: ctx.accounts.borrower.to_account_info(),
            authority: ctx.accounts.vault_authority.to_account_info(),
        },
        &[&[
            VAULT_AUTHORITY_SEED.as_bytes(),
            &[ctx.accounts.loan_account.vault_authority_bump],
        ]],
    ))?;

    Ok(())
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a [`setComputeUnitLimit()`](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/ComputeBudgetProgram.html#setComputeUnitLimit) instruction to the transaction:

```
import {
  Transaction,
  ComputeBudgetProgram,
} from "@solana/web3.js";

let tx = new Transaction();
// needs to be the first instruction
// experiment with this number to find one where the transaction succeeds.
tx.add(ComputeBudgetProgram.setComputeUnitLimit({ units: 200_000 }));

// add other instructions
tx.add(...);
```

Comment: this solved the issue. thanks.

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: any idea on how to do that using anchor?

Comment: @Dinaiscoding you should be able to use the transaction interface of anchor to get a transaction you can add the instruction to.